# How to call one GitHub Actions workflow from another and do not wait for it to finish to move to next task (fire and forget call)

Tags: github-actions, workflow, cicd

I need to call one GitHub Actions workflow from another template workflow.
And, as soon as the trigger to external workflow is done, the task in primary workflow should be finished (irrespective of the output - like fire and forget calls). And, then proceed with next task in the primary workflow.
Please share some coding examples with two sample workflows as per above scenario.

Let me know in case more info is needed.

I am able to call 1 workflow from another and other tasks in primary workflow are running parallely and moving forward.
But, the workflow is waiting on other workflow to complete for showing overall execution to move forward. Here, I need to just trigger and forget about the output on called workflow.

Comment: Could solution you have already?

Comment: You can check this https://dev.to/moaaz_adel/github-actions-a-simple-way-to-trigger-workflow-from-another-workflow-1b55

Comment: @KrzysztofMadej I can trigger one workflow from another and run task in parallel. Requirement here is to run another workflow in task and do not wait for its output and just forget about it after triggering. Can you help with this fire and forget scenario?